# Does Android OS 4.1 (Jelly Bean) use HWUI or SKIA?

Tags: android, skia

I have read an answer related to SKIA library here in stackoverflow that
Android OS 3.0 or above is using HWUI library.

I wonder if Android OS 4.1 or higher uses whether SKIA graphic library or HWUI library,
or it uses both.

Can anyone clarify my curiousity?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
both
```

1. when support hardware accelerate, it will use  HWUI library.
2. when you shut down hardware accelerate , it will  use skia graphic library (for example: in your layout file: you could use  **android:layerType="software"** )

Answer (score 0):

Android 4.x is using both `skia` and `hwui`.

Android 4.1.2 [manifest.xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest/+/android-4.1.2_r2/default.xml) lists `skia` as a dependency.

And `hwui` library is part of [frameworks/base](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.1.2_r2/libs/hwui/).